# Looking for a solution to fix http_client_requests_* missing issue

Tags: spring-boot, httpclient, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to enable Prometheus endpoint in my springboot project having below dependencies.

SpringBoot version:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

I am using *restTemplate* to make outbound call but when I check Prometheus endpoint, the data related with *http_client_requests* are missing
Looking for a solution to fix *http_client_requests_* missing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing this piece of code in a `@Configuration` file:

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
```

Which will somewhere downstreams add a `MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor` that produces the actually metrics utilizing a `Timer`